# Why SID is not coming in URL?

Tags: magento2, url, frontend, session

I am working on a multi-store configuration.

Store > Configuration > General > Web > Session Validation Settings > Use SID on Storefront is set to "Yes"

[image]

Store > Configuration > General > Web > Url Options > Add Store Code to Urls is set to "Yes"

[image]

Why I am not getting SID in frontend URL. I need SID in my all frontend URLs.

Comment: Did you found a solution? I'm facing the same issue...